# jQuery and variable nth-child not working

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

Here is a script I created in order to nicely display a gallery in a fluid/fixed container.

The point is to evenly position the thumbnails in their rows while keeping the first and last thumbnail of each row **against their container**.

To do that, i need to calculate the margin to be applied to each thumbnail and this is what this script is about (only the last part is relevant but I put it all here in case it would help).

I checked the variables and they are all ok but, for whatever reason, the variable inside the "nth-child" selector at the end of the script isn't selective and even if the variables are correct, the style is applied to all the instances of the "pic_block" class:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

     // Get the width of the container and thumbnails

     var containerWidth       = $('.container').width();

     var boxWidth             = $('.pic_block').width();

     // How many thumbnails can I have per row?

     var boxesPerRow         = Math.floor(containerWidth/boxWidth);

     // And then what is the remaining space left between the last thumbnail and the container?

     var marginTotalWidth     = (containerWidth-(boxesPerRow*boxWidth));

     // What is the maximum margin-right I can set to get an equal distance between the thumbnails (except the last box)?

     var tempMarginR          = Math.floor(marginTotalWidth/(boxesPerRow-1));

     // Then, what is the space still remaining between the last thumbnail and the container?

     var extraTotalSpaceWidth = ((marginTotalWidth/(boxesPerRow-1)) - tempMarginR) *boxesPerRow;

     // Time to set some variables that would help me dispatching the remainig space between the thumbnails

     var p                    = 1; 

     var i                    = extraTotalSpaceWidth;

     var marginR              = [];     


     // By default, all the thumbnails in a row (but the last one) get the same margin-right -> this will be fined-tuned in a later loop

     while(p <= boxesPerRow) 
     {
         if(p < boxesPerRow)
         {
            marginR[p]=tempMarginR;     
         }
         else
         {
            marginR[p]=0;   
         }

         $('.pic_block:nth-child('+ p +'n)').css('margin-right',marginR[p]);

         p++;
     }      

     // And if, after that, there is still at least 1px of extra space left...

        while(i >= 1)
        {    
            var s=1;

            // add incrementaly an extra margin to the right of each thumbnail of a row (except the last one) until there is no more space left

            while( s < boxesPerRow) 
            {   
               marginR[s] = marginR[s]++;

               if(i >= 1)
               { 
                   /********************************************************************/   
                   /* Here is the problem: this doesn't only apply to the nth-children */
                   /* determined by the "s" variable, it applies to all the class.     */
                   /********************************************************************/ 

                   $('.pic_block:nth-child('+ s +'n)').css('margin-right', marginR[s]); 

                   i--;
               };   

               s++; 
            }
        };       
  });

</script>
```

For the full code (html/css included) here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Pf7VV/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You have ('+s+'n)') that would be :nth-child('3n)') if the variable happened to be '3'

Comment: I believe you are saying that I have a "extra quote" issue but I don't see it.  Doesn't $('.pic_block:nth-child('+ s +'n)') become $('.pic_block:nth-child(3n)')? If not, can you be more specific? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on my last comment. I played with your code a little bit and am wondering if the number of images changes depending on the size of screen or do they simply change size? right now in your code $('.pic_block:nth-child('+s+'n)') is right but s=1 and so you are using nth-child is 1n. that is every single child is being selected. if you change that number then it will select that number of child so s=2 would select every other child s=3 would be every third child.

Comment: Neither the number of images nor their size is expected to change. I want to align them well and evenly while the 1st and last thumbnail of each row stays against the container. For the rest, this is the idea: apply a default margin to all the children (1n), then apply a "margin free" style to the last thumbnail (:nth-child(boxesPerRow)) and finally, add the extra-margin to some specific thumbnails in order to empty any gap between the last thumbnail of each row and the container. This extra margin could be applied to the first element of each row (n), the second (2n), the third (3n) etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pf7VV/2/ it looks like here that the margins for the center divs are spaced differently than the first and second one, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I don't see that in the fiddle but anyway: no, I want the space between the thumbnails to be as even as possible while the 1st and last thumbnail of each row must stick to the container.Let's say we have a container of 705px and 20 thumbnails with a width of 110px. The script computes that it will take 6 thumbails per row (660px) and that 45 pixels are dead space. so, it will use 7 pixels of right margin for each thumbnail to dispatch them evenly. So 660px + (7px*6)= 702px. Now we still need to dispatch 3px to fill the remainig gap so it will dispatch 1px to the 3 first thumbnails to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an unnecessary n beside your iteration variable s!

It should look like this:

```
$('.pic_block:nth-child('+s+')')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This would be true if I only had one row but I have an infinitely growing gallery and without the "n", this would apply only to the first row while I need it to work on any row. With you suggestion, nth-child(3) will apply to the third class while nth-child(3n) will apply to every class that is third element inside the row, will it?

Comment: I believe you are right, I did not understand the question :D Have you tried using flexbox? Here is a great article about it and may be an easier way to do what you are trying! : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I will check this, thank you but I rather not. It's good for me to try to learn from issues instead of avoiding them. As you can see with my code, I'm still a rookie.

Comment: Your code looks very complicated for a rookie, or maybe that's why your a rookie? I am semi new to javascript as well :S Good luck!

Comment: Exactly! I'm sure it could be achieved very easily if you know your code. Anyway, the logic is still there and the variable values tend to back me up. It's just the fact that the dynamic pseudo-class doesn't work as it is. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I can select using nth-child with jquery, probably the problem is in your html or in the selector

`.pic_block:nth-child(2)` doesn't mean the second child of an element with class `pic_block`, but the second element that has the class `pic_block`

See if this give you some inspiration http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/E8vN8/1/

EDIT

I think that this is what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/2JeK2/

Comment: My understanding of the nth-child is exactly the same as yours. I edited my question with the jsfiddle.

Comment: there is a syntax error in your fiddle: change `$('.pic_block:nth-child('n+'n)').css('margin-right',marginR[n]);` to `$('.pic_block:nth-child('+n+'n)').css('margin-right',marginR[n]);` I've edited your fiddle adding jQuery and fixing the error above, http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/P3XDA/ seems to be working

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction, it was a typo. The issue is still there though as the style applies to all the class, not only to the targeted nth-child(ren).

Comment: If you add a log line before the 2 css selectors like `console.log("first loop: " + n);` you'll find that at the 1st iteration n = 1, that causes the css to be applied to all the elements

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't get it, I'm sorry. If I put a console log there I get 1..2..3..4..5. And it's pretty what I expected to see. I'm not sure what to do with this info. Can you be more specific and tell me clearly what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: No worries. The 1st time you invoke `$('.pic_block:nth-child('n+'n)')` it'll be `$('.pic_block:nth-child('1n)')`, this will apply the css to all the elements. Then you reapply to the 2n 3n etc, but all of them already have the atyle applied after the 1st invokation.

Comment: Ok! But this is what I precisely wanted and the commented code is clear about that. For what I know, CSS stands for cascading stylesheets. So, I apply a default margin to all the thumbnails (1n) as I'm sure that it is a minimum margin they all share and then I go more specific by incrementing some of them in the 2nd loop to fill the remaining gap. So,I expect some of them to change their margin in that loop. And that's my concern:in the 2nd loop, they all change, not only the ones I target. I'm probably wrong, but this was my logic. I'm willing to change it for the best, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: To be as clear as possible, here is an example: if I only apply a margin-right of 12px to all of the thumbnails in the first loop and dismiss the second loop, all the thumbnails get 12px of margin, which is to be expected. But if I set 12px to all of them in the first loop AND add 1 extra pixel to some of them in the second loop, they all get 13px of margin at the end  and that is weird. So it seems that the problem is within the second loop, not the first one. Am I wrong?

Comment: does this give you the desired results? I tested different sizes and it seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/yUQvs/

Comment: Thank you for your effort. No it doesn't fit the bill because we can still see a small left-margin before the first thumbnail of each row and a small right-margin after the last thumbnail  of each row. They are not perfectly against the container. If these margins disappear and if the margins between all the other rows are as even as possible, it will be just what I'm trying to achieve. My last comment to Tlindell may help as I bring some real values as an example to illustrate the case.

Comment: Ok I've got what you are looking for eventually... http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/2JeK2/

Comment: Almost! You solved the left side as the first thumbnail of each row is against the container alright but there is still a tiny gap between the last thumbnail of each row and the container. This is the final small gap which makes it difficult (at least for me :-) Fill that small gap an you solve my nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work and the code is simplified (I got rid of 2 loops and 1 array)!

```
   <script>

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
         var containerWidth       = $('.container').width();
         var thumbWidth           = $('.pic_block').width();
         var thumbsPerLine        = Math.floor(containerWidth/thumbWidth);
         var marginTotalWidth     = (containerWidth-(thumbsPerLine*thumbWidth));
         var tempMarginR          = Math.floor(marginTotalWidth/(thumbsPerLine-1));
         var extraTotalSpaceWidth = ((marginTotalWidth/(thumbsPerLine-1)) - tempMarginR) *thumbsPerLine;
         var i                    = Math.floor(extraTotalSpaceWidth); 
         var n                    = 1;           

         $('.pic_block').css('margin-right',tempMarginR);

         while( n <= thumbsPerLine) 
         {      
             if(n == thumbsPerLine)
             {
                 $('.pic_block:nth-child('+n+'n)').css('margin-right',0); 
             }
             else
             {
                 if(i>0)
                 {
                     $('.pic_block:nth-child('+thumbsPerLine+'n+1)').css('margin-right','+=1');  
                     i--;
                 };
             };
             n++; 
         }       
      });

  </script>
```

Now, whatever the container's width, the gallery will always be perfectly diplayed with no margin on the extreme left and right position and the space between the thumbnails will be as even as possible.

Here is the jsFiddle (resize the result section and watch the thumbnails fit automatically the container):

http://jsfiddle.net/Baylock/ZkCgv/7/